# EF7 with SqlServer: violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint with composite key

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a table DataSourceDefinition that stores informations about different types of data sources. Since each data source naturally is assigned a GUID, I used that as the primary key.

Each data source type has certain settings which are numbered 1, 2 ...
I want to store informations about these settings (Name, Datatype, EditorType...) in a second table DataSourceSettingDefinition. I thought it would be natural to use a composite key consisting of the unique GUID for the data source type, which then would be a foreign key, and the Integer 1, 2... (SettingID) which is unique within a given data source type. The combination of both would always be unique.

When I try to insert two data source setting definitions with the following keys:

DataSourceDefinitionID - SettingID

5E880F15-80CA-45EC-AD5A-6D406B06AB08 - 1

5E880F15-80CA-45EC-AD5A-6D406B06AB08 - 2

I get the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY 
constraint 'AK_DataSourceSettingDefinition_DataSourceDefinitionID'. Cannot 
insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DataSourceSettingDefinition'. The 
duplicate key value is (5e880f15-80ca-45ec-ad5a-6d406b06ab08). at ...
```

Why is this not possible?

Here are my code-first models:

```
public class DataSourceDefinition
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }        
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string DescriptionEn { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class DataSourceSettingDefinition
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid DataSourceDefinitionID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int SettingID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string DescriptionEn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int DataType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**Update**

I forgot to show the code in my OnModelCreating. The prerelease version of the EF7 documentation states

> You can still add annotations to your entity classes so that they are used by other frameworks (such as ASP.NET MVC), but Entity Framework will not process these annotations.

That's why I left the data annotations in place and added the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<DataSourceSettingDefinition>().Key(m => new { m.DataSourceDefinitionID, m.SettingID });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a problem with the data annotations in these declarations:

```
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public Guid DataSourceDefinitionID { get; set; }

[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
public int SettingID { get; set; }
```

If I remove the data annotations and leave the primary key building to the fluent API alone, it works as expected. Although the pre-release documentation says data annotations would not be processed by EF7 there still seems to be a side effect. With the data annotations in place there seem to get generated a primary and alternate key but not a composite key. In that case the insertion of two DataSourceSettingDefinitions with same GUID of course has to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In EF 7

Unique constraints can not be configured using Data Annotations. You must use fluent API to configure it.

**How to Configure It**

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
            .HasAlternateKey(e => e.EmployeeCode)
            .HasName("AlteranteKey_EmployeeCode");
    }
}

class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```